# CSS file not working on Middleman

Tags: html, css, gulp, middleman

I'm new to coding so i could be missing something basic.

I'm on the 2nd project in middleman and this problem wasn't happening on the 1st one. I already checked the 1st but I just can't find the mistake.

When I inspect the page, my HTML shows the CSS file but nothing happens to the page. It appears an error on css and js files load. I already cleaned the cache, history and reloaded the page a lot of times and nothing happens. I did my 1st project 2 months ago with the same setup and everything was working fine. I just don't understand...

This is shown when I inspect the page:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, 
shrink-to-fit=no">

  <title>Casa Sporting Alfandega da Fé</title>

  <link href="/stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="/javascripts/all.js"></script>

</head>
```

I'm using gulpfile.js so the CSS file and the css.map were created through it after editing and saving the .scss file.

Here is the CSS file:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 500px;
  font-color: blue;
}

body {
  background-color: #459E63;
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Your imports are made with a trailing `/` meaning at the root of the web server... Is that the case? (Note that this is considered a bad practice)

Comment: Maybe try adding `..` to the front of file directories so like:
 `<link href="../stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet">` and `<script src="../javascripts/all.js"></script>`

Comment: @JulySFX My code is being inserted in ruby so it knows where to grab the file: <%= stylesheet_link_tag "style" %>.